# Integrating a directory watcher within Spring web application (or any java web application)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to incorporate a file directory watcher like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html within my webapplication.  I am trying to apply this to my spring web application that is an ecommerce application.

My basic workflow is a file is put into a directory and within that file, I would process the text file and execute some business logic that lives in the existing web application.

This would replace the process of someone going through the website and ordering items and submitting an order.

Is there any examples of this type of file handling within an application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of any pre-built libraries, but it seems to me like you might want to have some thread or scheduled task that simply remembers the last files in the directory in question, reads the current files, and compares the two.  This could be done as a Thread, part of a Thread pool, or some scheduled process using something like Quartz.  It all comes down to how you want to do it.

**Edit**
Further digging, it seems the java.nio library might provide a way to monitor a file system for changes.  Check out [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for more info.

Comment: I don't want to necessarily have it scheduled but when the event of a directory change(file creation) occurs, I would like to invoke the necessary business logic immediately.  Any ideas in that regard? libraries or custom creation?

Comment: Edit comment:  Yes, I linked that in my original question.  I'm wondering how you can incorporate within a web application (Spring).  I'm unfamiliar with invoking something like a static void main execution within a web application.  I don't know if that clarifies anything

Comment: You wouldn't implement it in a main method.  If you are following true MVC, I'd say the best fit for this would be in a service class somewhere.  Their example uses a standard Java application, which would require a main to execute.  It does look like you will need to implement some loop of some kind.  This being a web app, I would do this using a scheduled event (like Quartz mentioned above) rather than a thread with an infinite for loop.